# SXA Rendering Variant item index

Tags: sxa

I am using rendering variant to render list of items and i need to add special styles depending on the index of the item being rendered, is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. This is where the :nth-child() and the :nth-last-child() pseudo-classes come into play. You can achieve all that you want just with pure CSS styling.