# How do you create a promo with title, text, buttons, and image?

Tags: sxa, components

I received a requirement to show title, text, 1-3 buttons, and an image.

What is a possible way to produce something like the following?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to use a Promo component. There are several benefits to cloning the component but that requires discussion beyond the scope of this answer.

In the example image provided you would need these fields:

- Image
- Title - single line text
- Text - rich text
- Link - one more general links

Next create a rendering variant like the following:

[image]

The rest would be using CSS to properly position the image on the left and the content on the right.

---

There are numerous designs you can achieve with this approach. Here are a few more examples:

By throwing in a VariantPlaceholder you can add components into same promo (such as seen [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/28485/95)).

[image]

[image]

Here we are using the placeholder to render a Page List.

[image]

Comment: promos to the rescue